# variable of Class not being recognized in the function for Angular 2 typescript with GoJS

Tags: angular, gojs

I have an application which uses:

- **Angular 2**
- **GoJS for visualization**

It consists of:

1. *Parent Component*: **`src/app/search.component.ts`**

   it consists of a search bar and some area where a API call to the server will manifest buttons.
2. *Child Component*: **`src/app/search-details.component.ts`**

   it consists of a `<div>` which manifests the [GoJS Radial Layout Diagram](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/radial.html)

within the `SearchDetailsComponent` class of the child component there is a simple function called `nodeClicked` which is as follows:

```
nodeClicked(e, node) {
  // show the name of the clicked node on the console
  console.log(node.data.text);
  this.checkString = node.data.text // HERE is the ERROR....
}
```

Every time the Diagram is rendered and the user clicks on any node, an error occurs stating:

> TypeError: this is undefined

```
Stack-Trace:
execute/SearchDetailsComponent</SearchDetailsComponent.prototype.nodeClicked@http://run.plnkr.co/L7H44HHRrMceJAkj/src/app/search-details.component.ts!transpiled:96:21
Vh@https://unpkg.com/gojs/release/go-debug.js:539:43
Vg.prototype.standardMouseClick@https://unpkg.com/gojs/release/go-debug.js:537:201
ek.prototype.doMouseUp@https://unpkg.com/gojs/release/go-debug.js:667:73
E.prototype.doMouseUp@https://unpkg.com/gojs/release/go-debug.js:802:92
Ll/a.no@https://unpkg.com/gojs/release/go-debug.js:1012:149
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
onInvokeTask@https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3956:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:28
ZoneTask/this.invoke@https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:28
```

the `this` it is referring to is that of the `checkString` variable declares in the class `SearchDetailsComponent`.

How is the `checkString` not recognized? I have defined it above. This error keeps showing up with a **API service** I wish to call every time the node is clicked and a **HTTP GET** is called too.

What am I doing wrong here?

## [Live Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fGQnYLTbbJpd91b2wJY6?p=info)

## [Embed Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/fGQnYLTbbJpd91b2wJY6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @WalterNorthwoods' answer suggests. I created an inline function for the `Node.click` as follows:

```
click: (e: go.InputEvent, obj: go.GraphObject) => { this.nodeClicked(e, obj); }
```

the `nodeClicked` function is now callable and the `this.checkString` value is displayed perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The **Node.click** property is a function that will be called without binding `this`.

You could certainly specify a `nodeClicked` function that was a closure, if you need access to the outer component from within the event handler.

Comment: Thanks Walter. Again to the Rescue! I called an inline `click: (e: any, node: any) => {this.nodeClicked(e, node)}` and it works like a charm

Comment: Your arg types could be more precise.  Here's the declaration in `go.d.ts`:       
        click: (e: InputEvent, obj: GraphObject) => void;